# Why does object instances not show the properties of their Constructor.prototype even when they are inherited in JS?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor

I have some doubts with prototypes in  JS. It's too confusing.
So this is the constructor function I am using called Human.

```
function Human(fname,lname){
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname; 
    this.fullname = function(){
         return this.fname + this.lname ;   
    }
}
```

I have created two objects with it person1 and person2

```
var person1 = new Human('Barbara','Corcoran');
var person2 = new Human('Mark','Cuban');
```

So I get that person1 and person2 will have get fname,lname and fullname as its properties
but
If I were to say

```
Human.prototype.name = "Alfred";
Human.prototype.age = 28;
```

Here Human gets more properties namely -  name and age. Does person1 and person2 inherit name and age ?
If yes, then why doesn't it show up when I console log person1 and person2 ? If no, then why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name`  and `age` exist in person1 and person2's prototype, not their own properties.

The inheritance in JS is implemented with the prototype chain.

The prototype chain means if you access `name`  and `age` properties in person1 and person2 they will try to find their own properties. However, if the instances don't have these properties, they will try to find these properties in their prototype until the top of the prototype.

Normally, the console doesn't show the properties in the prototype chain. If you want to check these properties you should check the `__proto__` properties.

[image]

By the way, you might need this

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(person1)===person1.__proto__ //true
```

[image]